# Set an AngularJS date filter format to be used by all references to the date filter?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Rather that having to define a custom format for each call to the `date` filter, is there a way to globally define a default format (other than `'medium'`)?

I would like to have the format set in one file rather than all over the place in my code (the date format may end up being changed in the future and a modification in one file would be much nicer than having to make changes in many files).

This is what I am doing now (defining date format each time):

```
{{systemTime | date:'dd MMMM @ HH:mm:ss'}}
{{modifiedTime | date:'dd MMMM @ HH:mm:ss'}}
{{getShippedTime() | date:'dd MMMM @ HH:mm:ss'}}
   etc.
```

I was thinking of creating a custom filter (let's call it `myDate`), which would act as a wrapper and then pass off the date string to the Angular `date` filter with my custom format, so then my code could just look like this:

```
{{systemTime | myDate}}
{{modifiedTime | myDate}}
{{getShippedTime() | myDate}}
   etc.
```

However, I can't figure out how to make the `myDate` filter point to the Angular `date` filter.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236905/how-to-extend-or-override-existing-filters-in-angularjs

Comment: http://angulartutorial.blogspot.in/2014/04/date-filtering-and-formatting-in.html

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Based on some more research and then considering the comment by moderndegree, I have found that the following `myDate` filter will work:

```
.filter('myDate', function($filter) {    
    var angularDateFilter = $filter('date');
    return function(theDate) {
       return angularDateFilter(theDate, 'dd MMMM @ HH:mm:ss');
    }
});
```

Comment: You can also include 'dateFilter' instead of including '$filter' and grabbing the date filter from that by name. 'fooFilter' is automatically available as a dependency name when you define a 'foo' filter.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
angular.module('yourmodule').filter('myDate', function($filter)
{
    return function(input)
    {
        if(input == null){ return ""; }
        var _date = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'dd MMMM @ HH:mm:ss');
        return _date.toUpperCase();
    };
});
```

Html

```
{{systemTime | myDate}}
```

[Date filtering and formatting in Angular js.](http://angulartutorial.blogspot.in/2014/04/date-filtering-and-formatting-in.html)

Answer (score 5):

### Use a decorator,

It's not what you explicitly asked for, use a [decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator). it's built in angular and designed to patch `services`, `directives`, `filters` etc ...

in your case, if the date filter is not provided, you should use your custom date format.

```
app.config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('dateFilter', function ($delegate) {
        return function () {

            // Check if the date format argument is not provided
            if (!arguments[1]) { 
                arguments[1] = 'dd MMMM @ HH:mm:ss';
            }

            var value = $delegate.apply(null, arguments);
            return value;
        };
    })
});
```

Comment: I like this answer, but beware that arguments cant be updated directly, you need to do something like `var args = Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments)` before checking and updating it.

Comment: Very elegant - I think it is better than declaring another a custom filter.

Answer (score 2):

The `format` defaults to `mediumDate` if none is provided. There is nothing built in to have it default to something else.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filters.js#L382

Answer (score 0):

In case  you are working with .aspx pages and have the date format stored in a configuration file...

1. From the .aspx that injects your Angular page, set a global variable with the web.config date format

   var _settingsDateFormat = '<%=appSettings.DateFormat%>';
2. Set a global filter to be used through your  app

```
yourModule.filter('myDateFormat', function ($filter) {
        return function (input) {
            if (input == null) { return ""; }
            var formattedDate = $filter('date')(new Date(input), _settingsDateFormat);
            return formattedDate;
        };
});
```

3. Just add the custom filter to your dates

```
       Effective {{row.StartDate|myDateFormat}} - {{row.StopDate|myDateFormat}}
```