# Implementing "nulls first" sort order in AngularJS ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'm attempting to establish default order by / sort order on two string columns in ng-grid , but the default action is to throw null values to the bottom regardless of asc / desc.

If I want null values to be displayed first, is there a built-in option I'm missing similar to Oracle SQL's "nulls first"?  If not, any quick tips on writing such an external sort?

Comment: maybe take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662001/angular-sorting-with-null-objects

Comment: Thanks, that link helps in pre-ordering the array before ng-grid.  Have to play around (possibly with external sorting) in ng-grid to find out how to maintain that as once a user sorts by a column, there's no "third state" on the sort to turn it off and return to my original order.