# AngularJS: OrderBy Descending (null entries)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I'm using Angular JS and Google Places API to build an web app.

I have an **ng-repeat** which is currently being ordered by "rating" descending(**orderBy:'-rating'**). So it will list x places from the Google Places API JSON file in the descending order based on the rating.

HOWEVER, items/places that don't have a rating are classed as null and these entries are shown at the top of my ng-repeat feed. These should go to the bottom of the feed as they don't have a rating?

So an example of how i'd like this it to look is:

```
<ng-repeat orderBy:'-rating'>
  <place rating="5"/>
  <place rating="4.2"/>
  <place rating="2.8"/>
  <place rating="null"/>
  <place rating="null"/>
</ng-repeat>
```

What's the best way of going about this?

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604374/angularjs-orderby-with-empty-field/30028814

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To sort with `null` or `undefined` value using `orderBy` filter. use `[]` notation `orderBy:[ '!rating', '-rating', ]`.

That will show `null` or `undefined` value at the bottom.

like:

```
 <li ng-repeat="option in options | orderBy:[ '!rating', '-rating', ]">{{option.name}}</li>
```

If you want **only** null values to go to the bottom you can use:

`orderBy: [ 'rating === null', '-rating' ]`

For all falsy values except 0 you can do:

`orderBy: [ 'rating !== 0 && !rating', '-rating' ]`

Comment: Thanks, this worked a treat. Wasn't aware that you could use arrays in the orderBy filter. I'm glad I didn't have to waste time to write up a custom filter.

Comment: Well it's working on page load setting it to the scoped variable. But it doesn't  seem to work in my select box. 

My code is like so:

View:
<ng-repeat="orderBy:Events.order"/>

<select>
   <option value="['!rating', '-rating']">High to Low</option>
</select>

Controller:
vm.order = ['!rating','-rating'];

Comment: could you clarify more what do you want by update your answer ?

Comment: So when a user clicks on the option sort by: 'High to Low' it should re-filter the array to [!rating, -rating]. But this value doesn't seem to work in a select box.

Comment: It seems to also show 0 (zero) at the bottom.  Any way to not include these at the bottom?

Comment: for your requirement you may need to create custom filter :)@Jeremy

Comment: solution worked for me, you can also add double exclamations to switch the order of the null or undefined: orderBy: ['!!rating', '-rating']
Needed this and couldn't find it here