# Angular order by nested properties which may be missing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I have a list with items, and as you can see in the [following](http://plnkr.co/edit/QBC7a6BM9785I5CTtbAj?p=preview) plunkr, I'm trying to sort the table, using standard `orderBy` filter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in list | orderBy: sorting.field : sorting.reverse">
     <!-- some code goes here -->
</tr>
```

See the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QBC7a6BM9785I5CTtbAj?p=preview) or snippet below:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.list = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'test 1',
    reactions: {
      'like': 7,
      'share': 20,
      'comment': 100
    }
  }, {
    id: 2,
    title: 'test 2',
    reactions: {
      'like': 5,
      'share': 10,
    }
  }, {
    id: 3,
    title: 'test 3',
    reactions: {
      'like': 4,
      'share': 1,
    }
  }, {
    id: 4,
    title: 'test 4',
    reactions: {
      'like': 4,
      'share': 1,
      'comment': 2
    }
  }];

  $scope.sorting = {
    field: 'id',
    reverse: false
  };


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.5"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th ng-click="sorting.field = 'id'; sorting.reverse = ! sorting.reverse;">ID</th>
        <th ng-click="sorting.field= 'title'; sorting.reverse = ! sorting.reverse;">Title</th>
        <th ng-click="sorting.field = 'reactions.like'; sorting.reverse = ! sorting.reverse;">Likes</th>
        <th ng-click="sorting.field = 'reactions.share'; sorting.reverse = ! sorting.reverse;">Shares</th>
        <th ng-click="sorting.field = 'reactions.comment'; sorting.reverse = ! sorting.reverse;">Comments</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in list | orderBy: sorting.field : sorting.reverse">
        <td>
          {{item.id}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{item.title}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{item.reactions.like}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{item.reactions.share}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{item.reactions.comment}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="hint">
      <p>* Click on table heading in order to sort results.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem comes when some properties are missing (*n.b. - can't handle this, as the data comes from external API*), take a look at "Comments" column and you'll see what I'm talking about. The data is not sorted as expected.

Yes, I tried everything from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604374/angularjs-orderby-with-empty-field) thread, but nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: What do you expect? If there are *no* comments, should it should be considered as `0` and show up at the beginning when sorted asc? Why can't you *fix* these values before assigning them to the scope? In coffee it would be `item.comments ?= 0 for item in items`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hacking with sorting (you can apply [any sort function you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040395/custom-sort-function-in-ng-repeat)) you should fix the data before displaying them.

```
var possibleReactions = ['like', 'share', 'comment'];
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.list.length; i++) {
  var item = $scope.list[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < possibleReactions.length; j++) {
    var reaction = possibleReactions[j];
    if(!item.reactions[reaction]) item.reactions[reaction] = 0;
  }
}
```

Check out the working snippet below.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.list = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'test 1',
    reactions: {
      'like': 7,
      'share': 20,
      'comment': 100
    }
  }, {
    id: 2,
    title: 'test 2',
    reactions: {
      'like': 5,
      'share': 10,
    }
  }, {
    id: 3,
    title: 'test 3',
    reactions: {
      'like': 4,
      'share': 1,
    }
  }, {
    id: 4,
    title: 'test 4',
    reactions: {
      'like': 4,
      'share': 1,
      'comment': 2
    }
  }];
  
  var possibleReactions = ['like', 'share', 'comment'];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.list.length; i++) {
    var item = $scope.list[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < possibleReactions.length; j++) {
      var reaction = possibleReactions[j];
      if(!item.reactions[reaction]) item.reactions[reaction] = 0;
    }
  }

  $scope.sorting = {
    field: 'id',
    reverse: false
  };


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.5"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th ng-click="sorting.field = 'id'; sorting.reverse = ! sorting.reverse;">ID</th>
        <th ng-click="sorting.field= 'title'; sorting.reverse = ! sorting.reverse;">Title</th>
        <th ng-click="sorting.field = 'reactions.like'; sorting.reverse = ! sorting.reverse;">Likes</th>
        <th ng-click="sorting.field = 'reactions.share'; sorting.reverse = ! sorting.reverse;">Shares</th>
        <th ng-click="sorting.field = 'reactions.comment'; sorting.reverse = ! sorting.reverse;">Comments</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in list | orderBy: sorting.field : sorting.reverse">
        <td>
          {{item.id}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{item.title}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{item.reactions.like}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{item.reactions.share}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{item.reactions.comment}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="hint">
      <p>* Click on table heading in order to sort results.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most common thing you can do is following

```
<td>
 <span ng-if="item.reactions.comment">{{item.reactions.comment}}</span>
 <span ng-if="!item.reactions.comment">Zero</span>
</td>
```

If you find a more precise way then update here.

Comment: This does not solve the problem of sorting by this value. Also, it would be much easier like that `<td>{{ item.reactions.comments || 0 }}</td>`.

Answer (score 0):

create your own filter

```
angular
.module("app", [])
.controller("c", function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {id: 1, name: ""},
        {id: 2, name: "a"},
        {id: 3, name: "b"},
        {id: 4, name: "c"},
        {id: 5, name: ""},
        {id: 6, name: "f"},
        {id: 7, name: ""},
        {id: 8, name: "z"},
    ];
})
.filter("emptyToEnd", function () {
    return function (array, key) {
        var present = array.filter(function (item) {
            return item[key];
        });
        var empty = array.filter(function (item) {
            return !item[key]
        });
        return present.concat(empty);
    };
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
```

see working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yCMVB/)