# Using angularjs add colon in time zone

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, css

```
{{1288323623006 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}: 2010-10-29 09:10:23 +0530
```

I want to time zone with colon like +05:30 in angularjs.

Comment: Can you explain better your needs? What output do you want?

Comment: He wants +05:30 instead of +0530. But `'Z': 4 digit (+sign) representation of the timezone offset (-1200-+1200)` is what is in the documentation so I dont think you can.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the below

```
{{ d = (1288323623006 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z').split(''); d.splice(-2, 0, ':'); d.join('') }}
```

but a better (and cleaner) way would be to write your own custom filter.

*Note - by the way, angular expressions do not support regular expression literals (in case you are thinking of simplifying it that way) - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression*

Answer (score 0):

I referenced this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236905/how-to-extend-or-override-existing-filters-in-angularjs), when I developed this answer:

```
myApp.config(['$provide', function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('dateFilter', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
    return function() {
      var args = arguments;
      // Replace my 'ZZ' option with a 'Z' I can find
      args[1] = args[1].replace('ZZ', '!!Z!!');
      // Get the original, Angular output
      original = $delegate.apply(this, args);
      // Find my marked time zones, clean up, and add the colon
      return original.replace(/!!([-|+]?)(\d\d)(\d\d)!!/, '$1$2:$3');
    };
  }])
}]);
```

You can see a JSFiddle of it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ricksmt/9dg0hLho/28/embedded/result/). This approach opts to extend the built-in date filter with a `ZZ` option for a timezone with a colon. The only thing this doesn't account for is escaped letters, but that's not a problem on my project with this extension. You may need to check for that, especially if you override the original `Z` option.