# How can I override Angular's number filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I want to make Angular's number filter to have one and the same format no matter the chosen localization.

So, from the [Angular source in GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filters.js#L79) I saw that the implementation of the filter looks like this:

```
function numberFilter($locale) {
   var formats = $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS;
   return function(number, fractionSize) {

       // if null or undefined pass it through
       return (number == null)
           ? number
           : formatNumber(number, formats.PATTERNS[0], formats.GROUP_SEP, formats.DECIMAL_SEP,
                   fractionSize);
    };
}
```

I want my numbers to look like this: 123 456.78. Meaning,

```
formats.GROUP_SEP = " "; // Always, disrespect locale
formats.DECIMAL_SEP = "."; // Always, disrespect locale
```

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25956062/2419808) about overriding existing filters, but I can't figure out how to use it in my case to achieve exactly what I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override $locale to use your own values like this:

```
var app = angular.module("test", []);

app.run(["$locale", function ($locale) {
    $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.GROUP_SEP = " ";
    $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.DECIMAL_SEP = ".";
}]);
```

Plnkr link: https://plnkr.co/edit/DlacehjcZrFRmWNFs1qZ?p=preview

Comment: Wow, that's a nice solution, but it doesn't work for me because I'm changing the localization dynamically with https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale. Any idea how to make this two things work together?

Comment: Listen for an event emitted when locale change ? So you can force those values each time the locale change.

Answer (score 0):

You can override it like this :

```
myApp.config(['$provide', function($provide) {
   $provide.decorator('numberFilter', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {

       return function(number, fractionSize) {

           // if null or undefined pass it through
           return (number == null)
           ? number
              : formatNumber(number, formats.PATTERNS[0], ' ', '.', fractionSize);
      };
    }
   }])
 }])
```

Another way would be to setup $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS to always have the value you wants.

Comment: It does not work because formatNumber is a "private" function. angular.js:12450 ReferenceError: formatNumber is not defined

Comment: ah, then you have either to rewrite your own function or copy past all the private needed functions

Comment: then just write your own format number function or search for a tool on the net that does the job for you, that shouldn't be hard.